# Localhost port scaning report

Tags: nmap, portscan

I just enabled my firewall

```
$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
```

After scan my local host

```
$ sudo nmap -sS -sV -Pn localhost -p 0-6553

I got a result
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2023-03-25 21:34 IST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000015s latency).
Not shown: 6551 closed ports

PORT     STATE SERVICE     VERSION
631/tcp  open  ipp         CUPS 2.3
6341/tcp open  unknown
6342/tcp open  ssl/unknown

2 services unrecognized despite returning data. If you know the service/version, please submit the following fingerprints at https://nmap.org/cgi-bin/submit.cgi?new-service
```

My doubt is that I have not written any rule in Firewall. According to NMAP scan, 3 ports are open. I want to know the meaning of the port itself.

Thank you.

Comment: user68186 is not wrong, this is a scan of the local system and IS relevant to your output here.  I will detail what this means if you will do me a favor and also include the output of `sudo ss -tulpn` as well as an edit to your question as it will have more detail than `nmap` will and will help ID services.

Answer (score 0):

So, allow me to give you some insight into what you see here.

**Most importantly, you are scanning 127.0.0.1 - this is local services or services listening on all IPs.**  MANY services such as printing, etc. rely on internal listeners that can only be accessed from localhost in order to function - CUPS included (that's your print system).

You have three services that're visible on the localhost address - CUPS (the print polling system) on tcp/631 is well known and seen by NMAP.  That's normal.

"Service Unknown" is dependent on a signature being made for each service in NMAP's services mapping file.  While 631 is assigned by IANA to CUPS and `ipp`, the ports 6327 through 6342 are *not assigned* by IANA, and therefore does not have a services file entry in NMAP's known services.  It was able to identify 6342 as SSL but not a specific service.

This is where my comment to you asking you to run `sudo ss -tulpn` and then include *that* output in your question will help yield information.  Unlike `nmap`, `ss` will actually list what programs/daemons are using those ports that're being listened on.  This will help to ID the 'unidentified services' being listened to on your system.  It has *nothing* to do with UFW or your rules there, because a search on `localhost` runs on the loopback `lo` interface which is ALWAYS open for local computer communication to itself, and not something to be worried about in an `nmap` scan so long as you have the firewall enabled and disable external connections by default (this is the default in UFW).

Comment: Thomas Ward
Thank you very much